# Effect of philosophy on mental health

Tags: reference-request, health-psychology, positive-thinking, mindfulness

Philosophy involves trying to understand the world around us, and our thoughts, and ideas in general rigorously. This would lead to a lot of thinking about our ideas and feelings. This feels similar to some forms of therapy where we actively think about what we are thinking or feeling.

Furthermore, it feels that a habit of philosophising would mean that we are more aware/ mindful of our own patterns of thinking, and are more likely to identify harmful or faulty reasoning, or say, apprehensions without reason etc. This also should help in reducing stress etc.

All the above are just mt common sense guesswork, which can of course be all wrong. I am aware that reading at least some parts of philosophy, for example Schopenhauer as many say, may actually lead to more negativity.

So what I want to know is: are there good quality empirical studies on whether philosophising or studying philosophy if not philosophising, has any effect on stress, anxiety or other mental health related issues?

Comment: Checkout these questions on [philosophy.se]: [Is there any study about how half-baked philosophies encourage maladaptive thoughts?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/57006/19487), [Are questions about logical arguments in cognitive therapy on-topic?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3893/19487)